# How to add an image to every page in pdf flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created a pdf file with unknown number of multiple images (determined by user inputs). How to loop over them & add an image to each of theses pages? I tried this statement but it didn't work:

```
pdf.document.pdfPageList.pages[i].contents.add(doc.PdfImage.file(pdf.document, bytes: logo));
```

Answer (score 1):

To add an image to every page in a PDF document in Flutter, you can loop through the pages and add the image to each page. You can use the pdf package to accomplish this. Here's an example of how to do it.

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> addImagesToPDF() async {
  // Create a PDF document
  final pdf = pw.Document();

  // Replace this with your image data
  final imageBytes = File('path_to_your_image.png').readAsBytesSync();

  // Loop through the pages and add the image to each page
  for (int i = 0; i < pdf.pagesCount; i++) {
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return pw.Center(
            child: pw.Image(
              MemoryImage(imageBytes), // Create an image widget with your image data
              width: 200, // Set the width and height as needed
              height: 200,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  // Save the PDF to a file
  final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final file = File('${output.path}/example.pdf');
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
}

void main() async {
  await addImagesToPDF();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.